WRDS connection R Studio
I try to use the code (using my password and username) from Tidy Finance:
https://www.tidy-finance.org/r/wrds-crsp-and-compustat.html
*wrds <- dbConnect(
Postgres(),
host = "wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu",
dbname = "words",
port = 9737,
sslmode = "require",
user = Sys.getenv("WRDS_USER"),
password = Sys.getenv("WRDS_PASSWORD"))*

I get the following error: Error: connection to server at "wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu" (165.123.60.118), port 9737 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Have you checked the values of Sys.getenv("WRDS_USER") and Sys.getenv("WRDS_PASSWORD") Do they exist and return the expected values?

It should be dbname = "wrds". Note that if you have set up a ~./pgpass file, you don't need WRDS_PASSWORD or to set password. And if your WRDS ID is the same as your login ID on your computer or you have PG_USER set, you don't need to set user.
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

wrds <- dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host = "wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu",
  dbname = "wrds",
  port = 9737,
  sslmode = "require")

tbl(wrds, Id("crsp", "dsi"))
#> # Source:   table<"crsp"."dsi"> [?? x 11]
#> # Database: postgres  [xxxx@wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu:9737/wrds]
#>    date          vwretd    vwretx   ewretd   ewretx sprtrn spindx  totval totcnt
#>    <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
#>  1 1925-12-31 NA        NA        NA       NA           NA     NA  2.75e7    503
#>  2 1926-01-02  0.00569   0.00569   0.00952  0.00952     NA     NA  2.76e7    497
#>  3 1926-01-04  0.000706  0.000706  0.00578  0.00578     NA     NA  2.76e7    502
#>  4 1926-01-05 -0.00482  -0.00487  -0.00193 -0.00203     NA     NA  2.75e7    501
#>  5 1926-01-06 -0.000423 -0.000427  0.00118  0.00116     NA     NA  2.76e7    505
#>  6 1926-01-07  0.00499   0.00495   0.00845  0.00838     NA     NA  2.77e7    504
#>  7 1926-01-08 -0.00324  -0.00355  -0.00169 -0.00194     NA     NA  2.75e7    502
#>  8 1926-01-09  0.00221   0.00221   0.00331  0.00331     NA     NA  2.74e7    498
#>  9 1926-01-11 -0.00854  -0.00861  -0.00994 -0.0100      NA     NA  2.74e7    504
#> 10 1926-01-12 -0.000929 -0.000929 -0.00362 -0.00362     NA     NA  2.74e7    502
#> # ℹ more rows
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: usdval <dbl>, usdcnt <int>

Created on 2024-08-01 with reprex v2.1.1
